# How to debug RestApi deployed on local server using Vs code for Go Language

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, delve

How to debug RestApi deployed on local server using Vs code for Go Language.
I have gone through delve docs and made the settings. I have a local server, With java client i am trying to get the response. The localhost server is running on debug mode but flow is not stopping on breakpoints. The code is in Go language and i am using VSCode IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you have proper Go lang setup for VS Code. Otherwise just check [this](https://www.jaganathanb.in/2018/07/how-to-start-with-go-language-googles.html) link.

**Note:** You have to run your Go RestApi through VS Code

Answer (score -1):

VSCode has pretty good wiki page about it on their [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-go/wiki/Debugging-Go-code-using-VS-Code)

I do not want to quote whole docs here. Quick summary of steps would be:

1. Install delve
2. Set up configurations in `launch.json`

And you are ready.